# In chrome, when in youtube, and I change the windows volume, play buttons appear. How do I remove them?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, youtube

I'm changing the windows volume with my lenovo hotkeys (fn keys). I want the volume block to appear, I just don't want the play buttons block to appear. It only happens on youtube. It only started recently and I have no idea how it was turned on. How do I disable it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to chrome://flags/ , search there for 'media' and disable the 'Hardware Media Key Handling' flag. That should fix it.

Comment: You're my hero, thank you!